# Find distinct elements that match multiple values from the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say this is the table I am talking about

```
id      pId     fId
1       1       1
2       2       1
3       2       2
4       3       2
```

I need to get a list of pId's who have a match to ALL of the given indices in a list of fId's.

What I mean is ->

Consider the list of fId's to be:

```
(1,2)
```

Then the result should be

```
2
```

Because only pId 2 has a match to all given entries in the list of fId's (which would be 1 and 2).

I couldn't find any way to do it so far - any help is highly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate on pid column and use a `having` clause.

```
select pid
from tablename
group by pid
having sum(case when fid in (1,2) then 1 else 0 end) >= 2
```